# Jhipster ng-dragdrop

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

Im new to angularjs and I am experimenting with the Jhipster framework.

I'm trying create an angular module which can drag and drop components. However my code already fails at initialisation.

What I've done:

I installed angular-dragdrop: **bower install angular-dragdrop**

I updated my bower.json:

```
{ "stomp-websocket": "2.3.4",
"sockjs-client": "0.3.4",
"bootstrap": "3.3.4",
"modernizr": "2.8.3",
"jquery": "2.1.3",
"json3": "3.3.2",
"angular": "1.4.0",
"angular-ui-router": "0.2.13",
"angular-resource": "1.4.0",
"angular-cookies": "1.4.0",
"angular-sanitize": "1.4.0",
"angular-i18n": "1.4.0",
"angular-translate": "2.7.0",
"angular-translate-storage-cookie": "2.7.0",
"angular-translate-loader-partial": "2.7.0",
"angular-dynamic-locale": "0.1.27",
"angular-local-storage": "0.2.0",
"swagger-ui": "2.0.24",
"angular-cache-buster": "0.4.3",
"ngInfiniteScroll": "1.2.0",
"angular-bootstrap": "0.13.0",
"angular-dragdrop": "1.0.11" }
```

I updated my index.html:

```
...
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-dragdrop/src/angular-dragdrop.min.js"></script>...
```

However when I try  to initilize a module like:

```
angular.module('hiptestApp',['ngDragDrop'])
.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $cookies, $http, $timeout) {

});
```

My whole Jhipster app stop working without displaying a any error message or whatsoever :(

I've seen dozen of examples on plunker which work just fine which do the same thing if you ask me.

Still it does not work so I hope someone of you can tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: Just got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Just got it working :)

I also needed to include:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

in my index.html.

I also forgot to save in bower :(

**bower install angular-dragdrop --save**

**bower install jquery-ui --save**

And finally added the 'ngDragdrop' in my app.js as argument.

Comment: You should not have to include it in your index.html, grunt or gulp will do it automatically for you, this is what the wiredep task does. Look at the docs, the best workflow is to run grunt serve and in another teminal run your bower install, you'll see the magic of jhipster build setup